# Extract text between last set of bracket in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, data-extraction

I have this statement in excel

> Blah blah blah blah blah(Pool 1 of 2) (science3262)

I want to extract the text `"science3262"`.
I have tried this formula:

```
=MID(A5,FIND("(",A5)+1,FIND(")",A5)-FIND("(",A5)-1)
```

It is giving me output as `"Pool 1 of 2"`

Comment: Is this last set of brackets always at the very end of your string? And is there always another set of paranthesis in front, e.g: 'Blah blah (number1)(number2)'?

Comment: Yes , the last set of bracket always comes in the end

Answer (score 1):

As per your added comment, I assume:

- The last set of paranthesis is always situated at the end of your string;
- There isn't always a 2nd set of paranthesis.

Therefor try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"(","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

Comment: Am becoming a great fan of `FILTERXML()`. Everyone should check out your excellent SO primer on `XPATH 1.0` functions for this Excel function.

Comment: Thanks Alot brother

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(")",A1)+3, FIND("(", A1, FIND("(",A1)+1) - FIND("(",A1)-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you write that the last substring will always be at the very end, then you can use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),")","")
```